# Reaction of copper(II) chloride and aluminium foil

Tags: redox, theoretical-chemistry

So I did an experiment recently with copper(II) chloride and aluminum. As they reacted with each other the redox reaction made the aluminum a brown substance that is supposed to be copper and the color of the copper (II) chloride solution was supposed to be colorless, indicating that the reaction has reacted ''evenly''. Even though I made all my calculations right and put the right amount of aluminum foil in the solution, the copper(II) chloride didn't become colorless. Could there be any suggestions as to why it didn't become as expected? Im doing a lab report on this and I can't seem to figure out any possible suggestions...
The calculations:
V(CuCl2) = 50 ml = 50 cm3 = 0.05 dm3

c(CuCl2) = 0.20 mol/dm3

m(CuCl2) = ? g

n(CuCl2) = V(CuCl2) x c(CuCl2) = 0.05 dm3 x 0.20 mol/dm3 = 0.01 mol
M(CuCl2 • 2 H2O) = 170.48 g/mol

m(CuCl2) = n(CuCl2) x M(CuCl2 • 2 H2O) = 0.01 mol x 170,48 g/mol = 1.7048 ≈ 1.705 g

(The 1,705 g is the copper chloride that was used to put in the distilled water to make the solution)

The amount went into 50 ml of distilled water. For every experiment, I was supposed to only use 10-20 ml so I used 15 ml for every try.

CuIICl2 + Al0 ⇸AlIICl2 + Cu0

3CuIICl + 2Al → 2AlCl3 + 3 Cu0

V(CuCl2) = 15 ml

n(CuCl2)= 0.01 mol

m(Al) = ? g

n(CuCl2) = Al x ⅔ = 0.0066666667 mol

n(Al) = 0.0066666667  mol

m(Al) = n x M = 0,0066666667 x 27 = 0.18 g

I even showed my teacher but i have no idea what could have gone wrong :/

Comment: This may be helpful: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/128099/79678. You should also show your calculations: a trivial math mistake is all it takes to ruin a calculation.

Comment: I edited them. Is there something that is wrong with the calculations?

Comment: Well one gram and 0,705 gram as well if that makes sense not 1,7 kg.

Comment: Or 1.705 grams if that makes more sense it's in Swedish so I understand if it's a bit weird but 1 gram + 0.705 gram.

Comment: Could there be unreacted Al *hidden inside* a shell of Cu?

Comment: So you mean that Al didn't dissolve properly in solution? Like there is a bit of coating that won't let it react fully?

Comment: That is highly probable.

Comment: @Poutnik Excuse me if I'm asking too many questions haha. So it is highly probable that the experiment wasn't done correctly or that the aluminum foil itself was the one that didn't make the solution colorless? I found a video where they used HCl as a catalyst that helped against this ''coating'' that the aluminum foil consists of.

Comment: HCl helps with Al2O3 coating, but not with Cu coating. It is not so hard to imagine Cu metal is obstacle for solution to reach Al.

Comment: Two mistakes. First : It is impossible to have a solution of $\ce{CuCl2}$ which has a concentration of $\ce{20 mol/L}$ . Look ! $\ce{20 mol CuCl2}$  weighs $\pu{2668 g}$. This cannot be dissolved in 1 liter. Second mistake : $\pu{15 mL}$ $\ce{CuCl2 0.2 M}$ does not contains $0.01$ mol $\ce{CuCl2}$.

Comment: Two other mistakes. If a sample of $\pu{15 mL}$  is taken from  $\pu{50 mL}$ of a stock $\ce{CuCl2}$ solution containing $\ce{0.01 mol CuCl2}$, the $\pu{15 mL}$ sample does not contain $\ce{0.01 mol CuCl2}$. No ! It contains $\ce{\frac{15}{50}·0.01 mol = 0.003 mol CuCl2}$. Second mistake, that I copy here : *n(CuCl2) = Al x ⅔ *. No ! It should have been written : $\ce{n(Al) = 2/3  n(CuCl2)}$. As a consequence, these $\ce{0.003 mol CuCl2}$ do react with $\ce{0.002 mol Al}$ , which weighs $\pu{0.054 g}$

Comment: Final remark. Have you weighed the sample of aluminum foil introduced into the solution? It must have been at least $\pu{0.054 g}$ ! If some copper ions were still in solution at the end, it may have been for lack of aluminum !...

Comment: @Maurice Thanks a lot for pointing the mistakes out! :) I'll make sure to fix them as much as I can.