# Question about reaction in battery

Tags: redox, electrons

I made a battery like this.

$\ce{(-)Al|HCl,CuSO4|Cu(+)}$

By piling up 6 battery of this(actually I made this using 10 yen and 1 yen coins:10yen coin is Cu and 1 yen coin is Al.) I could turn on an LED light.
The plausible reactions taking place at the cathode and the anode are as follows.

Anode: $\ce{Al ->Al^3+ + 3e^-}$
Cathode:$\ce{Cu^2+ +2e^- -> Cu}$  and  $\ce{2H^+ + 2e^- -> H2}$
[image]

I have an question here. Why doesn't all the electrons released from Al reduce $\ce{Cu^2+}$ or $\ce{H^+}$ immediately at the anode site?

https://cs.kus.hokkyodai.ac.jp/tancyou/vol.40/enn.htm

This url shows the battery on which mine based.
But I used paper wetted with HCl which contains CuSO4 , not NaCl saturated water like shown in the URL and picture above.

Comment: Be aware that attempts of theoretical evaluation of voltage and potentials of galvanic cells involving Al anodes is opening the [Pandora's box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora%27s_box) .

Comment: Could you draw a diagram of your cell and battery (collection of cells)? Also "10 yes and 1 yen coins" is not clear. What do you mean by this?

Comment: And aluminum metal reacts with both hydrochloric acid and copper sulfate solution. Your cell notation does not show any salt bridge, so I am guessing you used the different coins and suitably wetted paper or cardboard dividers.

Comment: I assume 10 yen coins are from copper and 1 yen coins from aluminium. // Some electrons released by anodic Al reduce H+ to H2 even directly at the anode.

Comment: @Poutnik I am currently working as a tutor. Actually, when I showed this experiment to my student she said why doesn't all the electron react directly at the anode site. And I couldn't explain. I would appreciate it if you could explain the reason.

Comment: @ananta Thank you for your comment. I added a picture and a URL.

Comment: @EdV You are right. I used wetted paper like shown in the picture I added now.

Comment: Well, the aluminum actually does reduce both copper ions and hydrogen ions directly at the aluminum surface, so this is a cell that is not very good: it essentially has a parasitic short circuit. But this means it just is not working as well as a proper cell with a salt bridge. It works, but not as well as it could. And using hydrochloric acid is not good anyway. So this is kind of a lemon cell. You would be better off doing what Volta did around 1785: use pieces of zinc and copper, no aluminum, and use saltwater to wet the paper spacers. Have fun as a tutor!

Comment: Here I show that aluminum reacts with a solution of copper sulfate and sodium chloride: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/128099/79678. Replacing the sodium chloride with hydrochloric acid would be even more favorable for reacting with aluminum. So other electrolytes should be used, i.e., not ones that spontaneously oxidize the aluminum.

Comment: I originally missed that there is a single electrolyte and cells have therefore wrong design, allowing Al to react with H+ and Cu^2+ directly, regardless being part of the galvanic cell settings.

Comment: @Poutnik Yes, it is just not a good cell design except for the copper! ;-)

Comment: @EdV Thank you for your explanation and URL. The experiment on the URL seems easy and interesting. . I understood that the cell I made loses much energy by parasitic short circuit. I will try to make a good cell with proper salt bridge.

Comment: Great! Have fun trying stuff: A. Volta’s “piles” design was used by Sir H. Davy more than 200 years ago in his discovery or isolation of several elements. Best of success!